# Floating point number comparison via integer casting in C language

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, comparison

I'd like to get an exact/precise answer why the following code prints different results:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(void)
{
    int a = 9;
    int b = 10;
    printf("%d\n", (double)a / (double)b == 0.9); /* prints 0 */
    printf("%d\n", (double)9 / (double)10 == 0.9); /* prints 1 */
    return 0;
}
```

I think this might be compiler dependent, mine is gcc (GCC mingw Windows7) 4.8.1 and gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2.

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE!**

I generated the assembly codes with and without the -std=c99 option, this should be helping to understand what is happening here.

Without -std=c99 (this gives the result 0/1):

```
    .file    "a.c"
    .section .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string  "%d\n"
    .section .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl   main
    .type    main, @function
main:
.LFB11:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl $-16, %esp
    subl $16, %esp
    movl $1, 4(%esp)
    movl $.LC0, (%esp)
    call printf
    movl $1, 4(%esp)
    movl $.LC0, (%esp)
    call printf
    xorl %eax, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE11:
    .size    main, .-main
    .ident   "GCC: (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2"
    .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

With -std=c99  (this gives the result 1/1):

```
    .file    "a.c"
    .section .rodata
.LC1:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $9, 28(%esp)
    movl    $10, 24(%esp)
    fildl   28(%esp)
    fildl   24(%esp)
    fdivrp  %st, %st(1)
    movl    $1, %edx
    fldt    .LC0
    fucomp  %st(1)
    fnstsw  %ax
    sahf
    jp      .L5
    fldt    .LC0
    fucompp
    fnstsw  %ax
    sahf
    je      .L2
    jmp     .L3
.L5:
    fstp    %st(0)
.L3:
    movl    $0, %edx
.L2:
    movzbl  %dl, %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $.LC1, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $1, 4(%esp)
    movl    $.LC1, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size main, .-main
    .section .rodata
    .align 16
.LC0:
    .long    1717986918
    .long    -429496730
    .long    16382
    .ident   "GCC: (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2"
    .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: This cannot be true... Could your print `a` and `b` as integers and check if they are 9 and 10? [This website](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php) also claims to be using the same compiler, and it prints `1` for both, like it should.

Comment: Prints 1/1 for gcc 4.8.2

Comment: Since floating point math isn't exact (and compilers store temporary results with different precision), I'd expect such behavior. But I also get 1/1 on gcc (x64).

Comment: You may be able to get more information by directly printing the two division results, to high precision, rather than by comparing them. My guess is that, with your compiler, the one with literals is being evaluated at compile time, the one with variables is evaluated at run time, and the results have different precisions.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: I spent a half day to find out this was causing problems to my program. I didn't believe it eighter, but it is true. Further information to the 4.8.1 compiler: it comes from MinGW on Windows7 (i don't know if it matters).

Comment: @BarnaBajak Anyway, you should not check floating point equality. Compare instead whether they are near enough, e.g. abs(a - b) < 0.00000001

Comment: cygwin 4.8.2 prints 0/1. I'm amazed that apparently the expression involving constants is evaluated at compile time (must be since there's a difference to the run time evaluation). Changing the int declaration to const leads to 1/1, i.e. compile time eval for the const vars as well. I'm amazed again that compile time code differs from runtime code (how so!?). As an aside, neither -mpc64 nor -msse2 nor -ffp-contract=off made any difference.

Comment: You might be interested in this blog post and its sequel: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/24/More-on-FLT_EVAL_METHOD_2 . Morality: use `gcc -std=c99` to obtain the behavior specified in C99 (for which both `printf` calls print `1`, for FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 0 and even for FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 2) with a recent GCC, and do not use Clang to generate 387 code if you care about floating-point determinism.

Comment: @QuasarDonkey In fact the C standard is a little more specific than “compilers store temporary results with different precision”. So there is still a question of what GCC is doing here (and the answer is “nonsense, because it was not passed the -std=c99 flag”)

Comment: `printf("%f %f %f\n", (double)a / (double)b, (double)9 / (double)10, 0.9);` What do you see?

Comment: @Oktalist: It gives the following: 0.900000 0.900000 0.900000 and with .100f it gives this result:
0.9000000000000000222044604925031308084726333618164062500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0.9000000000000000222044604925031308084726333618164062500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0.9000000000000000222044604925031308084726333618164062500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, floating point math is allowed to run in higher precision than the code indicates.
Especially the compile time math (2nd line) may run as a `long double`

> C11dr §5.2.4.2.2 9 "Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision), the values yielded by operators with floating operands and values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of floating constants are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be greater than required by the type.

See @Patricia Shanahan above.

---

[Edit]

Check the FP evaluation mode, if defined

```
#include <float.h>
printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
```

C11dr §5.2.4.2.2 9 (cont.) The use of evaluation formats is characterized by the implementation-defined value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

`-1` indeterminable;

`0` evaluate all operations and constants just to the range and precision of the
type;

`1` evaluate operations and constants of type float and double to the
range and precision of the double type, evaluate long double operations and constants to the range and precision of the long double type;

`2` evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of the
long double type.

All other negative values for FLT_EVAL_METHOD characterize implementation-defined
behavior.

Comment: Nice. -std=c11 enables the macro (which is 2) and prints 1/1. **g++** -std=c++11 still prints 0/1 though, and the macro is undefined.

Comment: GCC implements C99 (see http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2008-11/msg00105.html ) but sadly, does not activate it unless explicitly demanded by the programmer. Use `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` to activate C99-compliant FLT_EVAL_METHOD semantics in GCC.

Comment: @Peter Schneider Thanks.  I suspect it is possible to have `c11` and various `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` settings too.  I wonder what OP's `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` setting ?

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: Right, -std=c99 does it already. What it does, according to the docs, is to switch on -fexcess-precision=standard: "When compiling
C, if ‘-fexcess-precision=standard’ is specified then excess precision follows the rules specified in ISO C99; in particular, both casts and assignments cause values to be rounded to their semantic types" (p.128 in the PDF (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc.pdf), as opposed to _assignments only_ with -ffloat-store).