# Can't get the right answer with c++ STL map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have wrote a small map test program which is below:

```
void main()
{
    vector<double> price;
    vector<string> time;

    price.push_back(5.70);
    price.push_back(5.77);
    price.push_back(5.81);
    price.push_back(5.72);
    price.push_back(5.81);

    time.push_back("10:40");
    time.push_back("10:43");
    time.push_back("10:44");
    time.push_back("10:46");
    time.push_back("10:48");

    map<double,string> myMap;

    for (int i=0 ; i<price.size() ; i++)
    {   myMap[price[i]] = time[i]; }

    for (int i=0 ; i<price.size() ; i++)
    {   
        if (price[i] == 5.81)
        { cout << myMap[price[i]] << endl; }
    }
}
```

My expect outputs should be:

```
10:44
10:48
```

But the outputs I get is :

```
10:48
10:48
```

I don't know why it is wrong.

Comment: std::map is one-to-one. Since you have insert in 5.81 twice, '10:44' is replaced with '10:48'.

Comment: I suppose that using floats as keys could yield surprising results because (1) **The result of a computation usually is not exact.** If you try to find an entry in a map with a computed float result you may not find it. (2) There are even **more subtle problems** with floats, e.g. your literal 5.81 may not equal g in `float f = 10.0; g = 58.1/f`. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715793/floating-point-number-comparison-via-integer-casting-in-c-language, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238122/hash-function-for-floats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the *Unique keys* section of the [map specification](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

> ***Unique keys***
>        No two elements in the container can have equivalent keys.

This means that for each unique key (in your case, 5.81), there can only be one  value: the last one set (10:48).  For non-unique maps, use [multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/)

For discussion on the difference between multimap and map: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602068/whats-the-different-between-stdmultimapkey-value-and-stdmapkey-stdse)

Answer (score 1):

`myMap` can only store one value per key: the key 5.81 is duplicated.

You are overwriting the value "10:44" with your subsequent insertion of 5.81 -> "10.48".

If you want duplicate values for a single key then use `std::multimap`.

(Also, beware of using floating point types as keys. You'll hit problems with floating point comparison.)

Answer (score 1):

On a last iteration in first cycle you are updating myMap[5.81] previously added 2 iteration above (not add new element). Consider using std::multimap

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

> Maps are associative containers that store elements formed by a combination of a key value and a mapped value, following a specific order.
>
> In a map, the key values are generally used to sort and uniquely identify the elements, while the mapped values store the content associated to this key.

So you can only have one value per key, which is why it printed two time the same value.

Also, you can replace this portion of your code:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<price.size() ; i++)
{   
    if (price[i] == 5.81)
    { cout << myMap[price[i]] << endl; }
}
// by
cout << myMap[5.81] << endl;
```

It's more or less the same, if you don't consider the problem with `double` keys.

Comment: After the replace, it only gives one output which is 10:48.

Comment: Yes, but there's only one value anyway !

Comment: My wish is to print out all the time where the price is 5.81. So I need there be 2 times. But I know my way is wrong.

Comment: Using a map, there's only one time where the price is 5.81. You can also use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/